# Python 3 while loop can't show list keys?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ok so i am trying to do some basic while loop to show text formated in this way:

A - 80%-100%

B - 60%-80%

C - 50-60%

D - less then 50%

with this code:

```
dictionary={'A':'80%-100%','B':'60%-80%','C':'50-60%','D':'less then 50%'}
klucze=list(dictionary.keys())
q=0
while q<4:
print(klucze[q]," - ",dictionary[q])
q+=1
```

It's working with klucze[q] only, but when i try to print dictionary[q] too, i get the error

Comment: Why would you use a while loop there to begin with? ;)

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: You get *what* error?

Comment: `dictionary` doesn't have integer keys. `dictionary[0]` is an error, not the equivalent of `dictionary['A']`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing complicated things, use `dict.items()` method that returns dictionary key-value.

```
dct = {'A':'80%-100%','B':'60%-80%','C':'50-60%','D':'less then 50%'}

for k, v in dct.items():
    print(k, '-', v)
```

Output:

```
A - 80%-100%
B - 60%-80%
C - 50-60%
D - less then 50%
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked fine for me. I am just begining my story with python and i think i will have a lot if this kind of stupid questions, but try to sobie them on my own.

Comment: @GrzegorzMichalski no problem glad to help. Think about accepting my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Well dictionary accepts key to give you value at that key.
Your dictionary has keys 'A', 'B', etc. But you are using numeric value to access dictionary values thus it does not works.

```
print(klucze[q]," - ",dictionary[klucze[q]])
```

Now the dictionary is getting key values you created as input so it will give you the correct output.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. I replaced **'** with **"** inside dict items.

```
dictionary={"A":"80%-100%","B":"60%-80%","C":"50-60%","D":"less then 50%"}
klucze=list(dictionary.keys())
q=0
while q<4:
    print(klucze[q]," - ",list(dictionary.values())[q])
    q+=1
```